# Adding more data to MarkdownRemark nodes in Gatsby via a plugin

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'd like to add more information to a MarkdownRemark GraphQL node when it is created, via a Gatsby Transformer Remark plugin.

Currently I'm trying to do it within the plugin:

**gatsby-config.js**

```json
/* ... */
{
  resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
  options: {
    pedantic: false,
    plugins: [
      'my-remark-plugin',
    ]
  }
}
/* ... */
```

**plugins/my-remark-plugin/index.js**

```js
module.exports = async ({markdownNode, actions}, pluginOptions) => {

  /* Somehow add more data to the markdownNode which can be queried */

}
```

Just to be clear; I'm not looking to alter the AST nodes. I want to add more arbitrary data to the MarkdownRemark GraphQL nodes as they are being created, from within a plugin.

I tried using `createNodeField` but I can't spot the fields when querying.

Is it possible that a gatsby-transformer-remark plugin is not the place to do this? Fields are created when using a standard Gatsby plugin with `createNodeField`, but I am looking to do it from within a Gatsby Transformer Remark plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`createNodeField` will create fields under `fields`. In GraphiQL expand allMdx->nodes->fields. I use MDX instead of Markdown. Here is an example, which is similar to the examples in the Gatsby docs.

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({node, actions, getNode, createNodeId, createContentDigest}) => {
  const {createNodeField} = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
    const value = createFilePath({node, getNode})
    createNodeField({name: `slug`, node, value})
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a suggestion for doing it from within a normal Gatsby plugin. My question was intended for a Remark plugin. Have edited the question to make that clearer.